# Start and End day of the weekend per culture

Tags: javascript, typescript

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend (a table on this page have Weekdays per country).

Is there a way to get the weekend days per culture code in Typescript/Javascript? Most are Sat-Sun, but there are some exceptions.. i.e. Mexico = only Sunday, some middle-eastern countries = Fri-Sat, and etc. I would like to get Start and End day of the weekend per culture, if possible. moment.js doesn't seem to have this functionality (and there's a business-days library based on moment, but that one seems to be Sat-Sun friendly).

Comment: Unfortunately no, It's returning Sat-Sun for Mexico. Haven't checked all other.

Comment: Intl *is* the proper way to do this. If you disagree with some of the returned values for whatever reason, file a bug report on the API, or add your own special cases. But in general, it will return the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

[Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

> The Intl.DateTimeFormat object enables language-sensitive date and
> time formatting.

In particular see [.getWeekInfo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/getWeekInfo)

> The getWeekInfo() method of Intl.Locale instances returns a weekInfo
> object with the properties firstDay, weekend and minimalDays for this
> locale.

Comment: It seems to return Sat-Sun for Mexico, when it should be just Sun. :(

Comment: You can roll your own script using `formatToParts`

Comment: Not sure I follow. Different locale can have different weekend days and that too can change. Are you suggesting a custom mapping or something else? If custom mapping, that would be the last approach. I was hoping to find a prebuilt/built-in solution, if possible. If not, can you please elaborate?